# How do I save a whole MS Word document to single-paged PDF?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, merge

I am working with MS Word and there are quite a few places where I care about the final look of the document. I don't want to split certain parts (for example pasted source code). I also don't want to turn those parts into Objects, because while it would keep them unseparated, it will frequently add padding whitespace in the document around them. Web Layout works okay for development, but ultimately I will be exporting the document to PDF. I would like the resulting PDF to be just **one long page**.

How can I export an MS Word document to PDF so that the resulting file will contain just one page (result of merging all the pages, without seemingly random header and footers between the content)?

Comment: Save the document as a PDF then configure the page size within Adobe Acrobat.

Comment: @Ramhound is that option available in the free version?

Comment: No , but in Acrobat Pro, under Edit PDF, there is an option to have one page. That should help you.

Comment: @John thank you. I will try to acquire the pro version with my company's license and get back to this question to post an update.

Comment: You can also use any number of PDF editors.  If they are free or not is entirely up to you.  I have no specific recommendation.  You can certainly set the page size within the print options, but that does not make the PDF have a single page.

Comment: The maximum size for a Word page is 22" x 22". If that meets your needs, you can just set the Word page within that size and save as pdf.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon it doesn't. I want the resulting PDF to be a single page regardless of how much content is in my Word document.

Comment: @Ramhound I guess the hard way would be specifying the page size for every single exported PDF individually so they end up being a one-paged documents. Are there any better alternatives?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think that the PDF editor solution will give you a *truly* single continuous page. I think it'll still contain page breaks.

Instead there's a different way to go about it.
First you'll need to convert word document to HTML. I liked [this](https://cloudconvert.com/docx-to-html) online service for this purpose, but you could also use [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) to convert the docx to html, e.g.:

```
pandoc --extract-media='media' -s your_file.docx -t html -o your_file.html
```

Then, from HTML, you'll need to convert to a truly continuous single paged PDF. It can be done like so:

1. Get `wkhtmltopdf` - https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html (Don't forget to add on PATH!)
2. Open terminal and execute

   ```
   wkhtmltopdf -T 0 -B 0 --page-width 210mm --page-height 594mm input.html output.pdf
   ```

   Here, change the `--page-height` parameter to (297*Number of A4 pages) in your word document. For example, for 2 A4 pages it becomes 2*297 = 594mm

For more complex files containing extra files, extract the `.zip` first, then use

```
wkhtmltopdf -T 0 -B 0 --page-width 210mm --page-height 594mm --enable-local-file-access input.html output.pdf
```

Comment: I have done exactly as you suggested, but the resulting PDF is blank. I successfully converted the PDF into HTML, but the `wkhtmltopdf` invocation results in a 2KB empty PDF. Do you have any suggestions as to why did that happen and how to fix it?

Comment: I found [this discussion](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/2540) and by specifying `--print-media-type` option I got the resulting PDF to not be blank, but contain a single image and a line marker for the footer. No text or any other content, though.

Comment: @Fureeish This is really *wierd*. However it seems like a separate problem. I was successful at making a single-paged pdf using this. [Example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e6c-FIyfHxcjp2ljmP_17VYo1MGzNrWl/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Fureeish Oh wait..... I think, did you forget to replace `input.html` with your file name? That'll give you an empty PDF...

Comment: No, I replaced all of the names. Like I said in my second comment, by specyfing an additional option I managed to have a single-paged PDF with an image of my original document, but without any other elements. I looked at your example and your `.html` consists of very simple tags. Seems like `wkhtmltopdf` doesn't handle correctly all the elements. Have you tried converting a document that consists of multiple formatting, tables and images?

Comment: @Fureeish Was successful even for formatting, tables and images. Although, for images, and other files, use `--enable-local-file-access` as said above. [Example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1P7NyWQdps18VhyuGdTzmySBuuO7dsJfd/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Unfortunately, the PDF is still blank. My issue may just be too specific. I will try to create an issue on `wkhtmltopdf`'s official GitHub after delving deeper into the documentation. Thank you for the help. I will upvote the answer, but refrain from accepting it before I find fully working solution.

Answer (score -1):

I have a simple solution:
Convert to normal PDF
Upload PDF to
https://foxyutils.com/mergepdf/

Comment: No. The result will be **NOT** a 1-page document.